# P tag inside div: Setting margin-top to p tag pushes parent div down too

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to figure out why setting margin-top: 100px on the p tag brings its parent element down with it. I can't figure it out. Anyone got any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/HU4pR/

HTML:

```
<div id="Sections">
    <section id="Biography">
        <div class="InnerLeftSection">
            <p class="SectionTitle">Bio<br /><small>About Me</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="InnerRightSection">
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="Blah">
        <div class="InnerLeftSection">
            <p class="SectionTitle">Blah<br /><small>Blah blah</small></p>
        </div>
        <div class="InnerRightSection">
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Sections
{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    margin: -30px auto;
}

    #Sections section
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 468px;

        float: left;
        margin-right: 15px;

        opacity: 0.9;
    }    


#Sections #Biography .InnerLeftSection
    {
        background-image: url('/Shared/Assets/Images/BioTile.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;

        text-align: center;

        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    }

        #Sections #Biography .InnerLeftSection p
        {
            font-weight: bold;
        }

            #Sections #Biography .InnerLeftSection p small
            {
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size:0.65em;
            }

    #Sections #Blah .InnerLeftSection
    {
        background-image: url('/Shared/Assets/Images/BlahTile.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    }

        #Sections #Blah .InnerLeftSection p
        {
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-top: 100px;
        }

            #Sections #Blah .InnerLeftSection p small
            {
                font-weight: normal;
                font-size:0.65em;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because of the **collapsing margins** of CSS Box model definition:

[CSS 2.1 8.3.1 Collapsing margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins)

> In CSS, the adjoining margins of two or more boxes (which might or
>   might not be siblings) can combine to form a single margin. Margins
>   that combine this way are said to collapse, and the resulting combined
>   margin is called a collapsed margin.

From the definition:

> Margins of inline-block boxes do not collapse (not even with their
>   in-flow children).

So change the display of `p` to `inline-block` to avoid this behavior.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/HU4pR/4/

Comment: Thank you @Arbel Well that makes sense, but why haven't I noticed this in the last 7 or so years?

Comment: @deletethisaccount You are welcome! Glad to be of help to you.

Answer (score 3):

That is because of margin-collapse. When a block child is flush against side X of the parent block (assuming no border-/padding-X), the margin-X of the child will instead be applied to the parent. Just add this:

```
#InnerLeftSection { padding: 0.0001px }
```

Comment: This is a clearer answer as it mentions the child/parent relationship.

Answer (score 2):

Change `p` to either `inline-block` or `inline` instead of `block`

```
#Sections #Blah .InnerLeftSection p {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/6A984/)

Answer (score 2):

That's called collapsing margins: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins
Vertical margins collapse but not horizontal margins.

To prevent that, you can set the parent overflow to `overflow:auto` or `overflow:hidden`, or just add the parent any border or padding.

See it here (overflow): http://jsfiddle.net/HU4pR/1/
Or here (padding): http://jsfiddle.net/HU4pR/2/