# Why does the top paragraph margin touch the div?

Tags: css

```css
div {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.one {
  background: orange;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}

.two {
  background: lightskyblue;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="one">Paragraph One</p>
  <p class="two">Paragraph Two</p>
</div>
```

Why is the margin collapsing for the first paragraph? i.e. why is the first paragraph touching the div container?

Comment: Next time also add a code snippet in the question with a link to Codepen!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23206940/4982097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because both elements (`div` and `p`) belong to the same **[Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)** Therefore their margins collaps, **[margin collapsing](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/box.html#collapsing-margins)** is a property of the **[Block formatting context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)** by design.

---

If you want to prevent this, Make the `<div>` establish it's own **[Block formatting context.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)**

You can achieve this in numerous ways as described in the **MDN**

Here i used **overflow:auto** on the `<div>`

```css
div {
  background: gray;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  /* NEW */
  overflow:auto
}

p {
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-bottom: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}

.one {
  background: orange;
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}

.two {
  background: lightskyblue;
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="one">Paragraph One</p>
  <p class="two">Paragraph Two</p>
</div>
```